# Ejecutable en Python es bloqueado por antivirus

Tags: python, python-3.7, pyinstaller

Tengo un pequeño script realizado en Python y compilado a exe, cuya funcion es únicamente recibir una serie de parámetros a través de un archivo realizado en Visual Basic y enviar un correo con los parámetros recibidos.

El funcionamiento es correcto, pero muchas veces la ejecución del ejecutable Python es bloqueado por el antivirus y no se llega a ejecutar. El script fue compilado con PyInstaller.

En mi equipo puedo configurar el antivirus para que no bloquee esto pero la idea es que se ejecute en equipos de clientes para realizar envío de emails desde un software dentro del cual iría integrado.

¿Hay alguna forma de solucionar esto?

Muchas gracias por adelantado.

Un saludo.

Comment: Si tu antivirus lo detecta como código malicioso será por algo, no te  aconsejo que lo pruebas en las máquinas de los clientes.

Comment: NO ES DETECTADO COMO SOFTWARE MALICIOSO, lo manda a analizar y después te dice que es seguro, pero obviamente, no es factible que se repita en cada uso.

Comment: Eso sería una opción propia de cada SW antivirus. Si el antivirus ofreciera un API para que un programa se conectara y declarara "no soy malicioso", lo primero que haría cualquier virus sería llamar a esa API. Intervención del usuario (manual o mediante algun archivo de configuración) sería necesario, y completamente dependiente del antivirus.

Answer (score 3):

Tuve ese mismo problema hace algún tiempo. Debes tener en cuenta algunas cosas:

1. Es muy importante que **si tu ordenador tiene un procesador de 64bits tengas instalado Python de 64bits**. Si tu instalación de *Python* es de 32bits en un sistema de 64bits los ejecutables creados con *PyInstaller* suelen ser detectados como maliciosos.
2. El *compilador* utilizado por *PyInstaller* también debe ser de la arquitectura correcta.
3. Es aconsejable que [reinstales *PyInstaller* creando el bootloader tu mismo](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/bootloader-building.html) para asegurarte de que es el adecuado para tu equipo.
4. No utilices el *flag* **--onefile** al compilar. Los *standalone* generados por *PyInstaller* frecuentemente se detectan como maliciosos. En su lugar crea un instalador de tu programa con [InstallForge](https://installforge.net/), es muy fácil.

Antes de distribuir tu aplicación comprueba que no es detectada como maliciosa en [virustotal](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/home/upload).

Un saludo!