# Alternativa para convertir a exe en python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

Estoy teniendo problemas con pyinstaller ya que Windows Defender me borra los exe que genero, y si quiero distribuir mi app al publico, nadie podrá utilizarla por "supuesto virus", ¿Hay alguna forma de verificar que no sea un virus? ¿U otra alternativa para convertirlo a exe? ¿A caso siempre que se usa pyinstaller lo toma como un virus?

Comment: ¿Por qué es necesaria esta pregunta, si ya hiciste esta otra: [Windows defender me detecta mis exe hechos en PyInstaller como virus](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/449349/21) ?

Comment: Ahora tengo mas problemas, se me borra al crear un exe

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/379899/82862

Comment: Puedes probar [cx_freeze](https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) o [PyOxidizer](https://github.com/indygreg/PyOxidizer)